# Double-click cell on DataGridView in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, double-click

I am creating a lecturer's kit software using Visual Basic where the lecturer can save/edit the students' attendance. The student attendance will be displayed on a datagridview.

How do I program by double clicking a cell that automatically changes the default value of '/'(=Present) to two other input, either 'O' (=Absent) or 'MC'(=Medical Certificate). So far, I can only double click a cell and type in the data entry manually and save it.!

Any prompt response will be highly appreciated, thanking you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you explain further ? or more specific function...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly the cell will have data in it and when the user double clicks a cell you want it to cycle through presets for that cell?

You'll have to first get the cell that was selected, check what the current value is and then change it to the next preset. Something like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseDoubleClick
    If DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value = "'/'(=Present)" Then
        DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value = "'O' (=Absent)"
    ElseIf DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value("'O' (=Absent)") Then
        DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value = "'MC'(=Medical Certificate)"
    ElseIf DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value("'MC'(=Medical Certificate)") Then
        DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value = "'/'(=Present)"
    Else
        DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value = "SetYourOwnValue"
    End If
End Sub
```